# Search suggestion cache javascript

Tags: javascript, search, autocomplete, autosuggest

I am having a Search text-box for which I have to implement a search suggestion(like google search) kind of feature.

for example, if I type "abc" in the search box, I will get suggestions like
    **abc***def*
    *xyz***abc***xyz*

here each of these unique suggestion represents a jsp page whose url can be "hard-coded" in a java-script array. so when I click any suggested value, the webpage at the corresponding link is displayed.

For this, can you suggest me any efficient methods of implementing this.
*This must be in pure javascript, no third-party libs like jquery,etc., can be used*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The vast majority of Suggestive Search implementations use AJAX and a server-side script. Why is it important to use a hard coded JS Array?

Comment: Do you want to use AJAX or do you want to create your hard coded JS array in php or such when loading the page?

Comment: because in this case the list of values which will be displayed in the suggest drop-down is known before hand and it will never change.

Comment: AJAX or JS array whichever is faster. the the set of searchable strings is fixed(say some 50) and this set will never change.

Comment: Did you already manage to get the array into your page? If so, could you please show the resulting page code?

Comment: `this set will never change` - In this case AJAX of course is slower, because it would have to load and evaluate a page in the background.

Comment: I am still trying to get this Array in place. Since each searchable string will have a URL associated with it, shall I use JS Array or JS HashMap like implementation.

Comment: If possible can you please explain me how to use HaspMap in JS

Comment: As far as I can see, a HashMap in JS would just be an object / associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is in an [associative JS array](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jarray2.htm) similar to this

```
var locationArray = {
    'searchValue1' : 'url1',
    'searchValue2' : 'url2',
        ...
};
```

and your search input field has a function associated to `onkeyup`

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="UpdateSuggestions(this);">
```

then the rest is simple [JavaScript string functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp).